# E-Mail Sign-Up and OAuth Log-In - how to set it up with Devise on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, omniauth-linkedin

I have set up Devise to allow a user to register with e-mail. Now I have included a Log In via LinkedIn with omniauth. Therefore I had to save provider as well as uid in the users table.

The problem I have now, is that the combination of provider and uid should be unique. But when a user decides to register with email I don't have any values for provider and uid. How can I deal with this problem in a good way?

I am new to Rails and did not find any other answers to it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Get it from `request.env['omniauth.auth']`

More details here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Answer (score 0):

I would probably fill in `manual` in the provider and generate a uid with `SecureRandom.uuid`.

You could do this in your `User` model using a `before_validation` hook.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  before_validation(on: :create) do
    if self.provider.nil?
      self.provider = 'manual'
      self.uid = SecureRandom.uuid
    end
  end

...

end
```

You could also hook into the controller which creates the user.

If you need the uid to prevent a user from signing up twice with the same email, I'd use a sha256 hash of the email-address.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try that!

Comment: I got it working now. I had to add hidden fields to the sign up form so the create action would include the parameters provider and uid. But your provided solution worked like charm! Thanks a lot!